# Не работает exec и shell_exec

Tags: php, windows, exec

Я в PHP новичок и у меня возникла проблема с запуском exec. Основные данные:
ОС - Windows 2003 Web Server IIS -6.
При тесте:

```
    $out = exec('whoami 1>test.txt 2>&1',$output); 
    log_error("Error=".$out);
```

Выдает ошибку: `PHP Warning:  exec(): Unable to fork [whoami 1>test.txt 2>&1] in ....`

При тесте:

```
    $output = shell_exec("ls -lart");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Выдает ошибку: `PHP Warning:  shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'ls -lart' in....`

Я понимаю, что причина этих ошибок (предупреждений) одна.

Проверял:

- IUSR -  анонимный доступ открыт.
- phpinfo - в разделе disable_functions не указана ни одной функции.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в чем проблема?

Comment: В ОС стоит ограничение на кол-во одновременно существующих PID на вашем пользователе?

Comment: В разделе АppPool->свойства->Быстродействие->Web сайты я изменил значение с 1 до 5 (если Вы имеет ввиду это) результата не дала.

Comment: Да, еще. система запущена под admin со всеми правами.

Answer (score 0):

Утилиты **ls** и **whoami** - это утилиты командной строки в linux системах. У вас же Windows
Проблема вероятней всего в том, что у вас на сервере нет этих утилит. И поэтому они и не запускаются.

Проверить можно запустив **cmd** и уже там попробовать использовать указанные команды.

Comment: Я это уже пробовал, cmd на право проверял - прaва admina, В общем вопросе я это опустил, так как уже все это проверил.

Comment: Надо не права проверять. А есть ли указанные утилиты у вас в системе и находятся ли они в PATH - чтобы их можно было запускать из любого места не указывая полный путь до исполняемого файлa/

Comment: В данной ситуации CMD не причем, так как при тесте с ним у меня выдавалась та же ошибка, мне пришлось около недели сидеть (я писал, что новичок) что проблема не в CMD а в правах (или еще в чем-то), так как при тесте с разными параметрами НО С ОДНОЙ командой результат один, говорит о том, что проблема не в параметрах а в команде (или точнее в ее правах).

Comment: `whoami` на Win10 работает.  wikipedia говорит, что `whoami` входит в состав Windows Server 2003.

Comment: ESkri, Вы подтверждаете мою гипотезу, что дело не в параметрах а в команде. Но вот, блин, что с ней не так?

Answer (score 0):

Как говорится в одной пословице: "Спасение утопающих, дело самих утопающих", после 3 недель поиска я наконец разобрался в чем проблема, но я не хочу что бы моя информация исчезла и я решил с ней поделится. И так если Вас интересует это тема то на данный момент могу сказать точно причина у них одна: ПРИОРИТЕТ. Ища информацию на англоязычных сайтах выявилась 3 основные причины.

1. Если у Вас exec() выдает ошибку в параметрах которых присутствует **cmd** попробуйте тесты которые я делал (см. вверху) и ошибка не возникает - дела в приоритете (в правах на доступ) в самой cmd (с:\windows\system32\cmd прав.кл.мыши свойства -> безопасность окно "разрешение для SYSTEM" для действий ЧТЕНИЕ И ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ должно стаять РАЗРЕШЕНО)
2. Если же ошибка осталась возможно дело в **POOL**. Для IIS 6 и II 7 вот инструкция: [полная инструкция по созданию нового POOL (англоязычный сайт)](https://success.trendmicro.com/dcx/s/solution/1095592-creating-an-application-pool-in-iis-6-and-iis-7?language=en_US). Ищете вкладку с надписью II 6 или II 7 и открываете. Для тех кто не знает английского - googl переводчик. Инструкция позволит Вам создать новую группу и заменить струю на вашу вновь созданную - проверенно все работает.
3. Мой случай. Все что я опишу ниже соответствует для IIS 6, но суть для всех видно одна.
   Диспетчер службы IIS -> раскрываем список -> Веб-узел -> прав. кл. мыши. -> свойства -> безопасность каталога -> управление доступом -> изменить -> Анонимный доступ (должна стоять птичка). *Запоминаем имя пользователя.*
   Управление компьютером -> локальные пользователи -> ищем имя пользователя которого запомнили -> свойства -> членство в группе. В окошке должно стоять пользователь (не обязательно админ) с правами на чтение и выполнение, у меня же стоял гость.

Надеюсь, что моя информация сможет помочь.